# GET quote on polygon chain using 0x API

Tags: polygon, 0x

I can get quote from ethereum mainnet using this GET api call, the token are WETH and DAI

```
https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&buyToken=0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f&sellAmount=100000000000000000
```

If I modify the contract addresses for WETH and DAI on Polygon chain

```
https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619&buyToken=0x8f3cf7ad23cd3cadbd9735aff958023239c6a063&sellAmount=100000000000000000
```

I get an error, I have played around with sellAmount, it does not help

```
{
    "code": 100,
    "reason": "Validation Failed",
    "validationErrors": [
        {
            "field": "sellAmount",
            "code": 1004,
            "reason": "INSUFFICIENT_ASSET_LIQUIDITY"
        }
    ]
}
```

[This blogpost](https://blog.0xproject.com/0x-api-is-now-live-on-polygon-ce61faa2f99b) also confirms that 0x does support Polygon. So what am I missing from the API call?

Answer (score 1):

Found it

Prefix the chain name to the domain, in this case https://polygon.api.0x.org/

So this query will become

```
https://polygon.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619&buyToken=0x8f3cf7ad23cd3cadbd9735aff958023239c6a063&sellAmount=10000000000000000000
```